# .NET core web api Taking JSON input and returning it results in NULL output

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a web API that takes any JSON input, wraps it in an envelope (basically adding an ID) and then returns it, but I am having issues that the incoming JSON always seems to be NULL even though I am sending in valid JSON using postman

the simple controller is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace NWCloudTransactionHost.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TransactionInput : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index([FromBody] OriginalTransaction originalTransaction)
        {
            var transactionEnvelope = new TransactionEnvelope { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), OriginalTransactionData = originalTransaction };

            return Json(transactionEnvelope);
        }
    }

    public class OriginalTransaction
    {
        public string OriginalTransactionData { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransactionEnvelope
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public OriginalTransaction OriginalTransactionData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your json? It must have the exact same structure as OriginalTransaction.

Comment: {
 "jongel" : "pelle"
}

Comment: Hmm what I wanted was to have the incoming JSON be anything at all, I dont want to specify its structure hence I tried make it a string, I thought that meant I could send in any JSON

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Currently it expects a json in the form `{ "OriginalTransactionData": "[any string]" }`.

Comment: ok is there a way to make it so I can make it accept any type of JSON whatever the structure is on the inbound JSON?

Comment: I believe you could make the parameter type `JObject` instead...

Comment: Instead of string you mean it would accept any object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stream reader to read the body content stream. Then return a content result with `contentType: "application/json"`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Index()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        // Get the body (json) as a raw string
        var originalTransaction = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Wrap the transaction
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var envelope = $"{{ \"Id\": \"{id}\", \"OriginalTransactionData\": {originalTransaction} }}";

        // return json
        return Content(envelope, "application/json", Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Be aware that in this example there is no validation on the json. If it's incorrect (eg. missing a comma somewhere etc.), the answer won't be valid too. I recommed you the check if the raw string `originalTransaction` is valid json before wrapping it in the envelope.

#### Sample

Request

```
{ "Test": "Hello World" }
```

Response

```
{
  "Id": "a9258e99-86cf-4f1d-9e17-0df7ba1dce5e",
  "OriginalTransactionData": {
    "Test": "Hello World"
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I messed up a bit with my quick answer. Here's the revised version. I changed how to read the request json and how to send the response json back. This version should work now. Also fixed the invalid string interpolation and put the id in escaped quotes. Added a sample which worked for me.

Despite the stream reader I think it's more straight forward now.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) NWCloudTransactionHost C:\Users\MattDouhan\source\repos\NWCloudTransactionHost\NWCloudTransactionHost\Controllers\TransactionInput.cs 23 Active

Comment: @MattDouhan, I hope this works now. I didn't have time to test my first answer, I'm very sorry. If you have any question to my changes just ask.